# gitignore - allow folder creation but ignore all files inside - can we do it with exclamation mark (!)?

Tags: git, gitignore

When we push a certain project somewhere, we wish to deploy empty necessary folders too. For example: `/runtime/` folder.

However, we must ignore all files inside `/runtime/*` ;

I'm aware of "*the create a useless file inside your empty directories*" solution and also, aware of some sort of bash process to make that *add of useless files* automatic, but isn't there any other way?

I mean:

Is it possible to accomplish this by having on our .gitignore something like:

```
!/runtime/
/runtime/*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not currently. The [standard trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/) relies on having a file (`somedirectory/.gitignore`) in the directory, since git does not stage empty directories, no matter what `/.gitignore` may say.

It is currently not possible to `git add` an empty directory.

Comment: If you are excluding all files inside that folder, do not forget to exclude the .gitignore file itself.

`!.gitignore`