# Git: repo contains an empty directory - what happens?

Tags: git, directory

Git [tracks files, not directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091017), and we [cannot currently `add` empty directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600188/) (The [standard trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/) does not add an empty directory, but instead a file within, see also the [FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F)).

Nevertheless, a git `repo` may contain an empty directory. So what happens I clone a repo or checkout a branch containing an empty directory? Is it created in the work tree?

Answer (score 22):

To setup a test repository with an empty directory, you can use the following script (run it in a temporary directoy).

When checking out, however, the empty directory is ignored. Here too, Git only works with files, not directories, even if the latter are present.

Github and [`tig`](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/) display empty directories, [`gitk`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitk.html) does not.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo ---- initialize the repo...
#rm -rf .git
git init

echo ---- create an empty tree object...
empty_tree=$(git mktree < /dev/null)

echo ---- create a parent tree containing the empty subtree...
root_tree_ls=$(echo -e 040000 tree $empty_tree\\tvacuum)
root_tree=$(echo "$root_tree_ls" | git mktree)

echo ---- commit...
commit_msg="This commit contains an empty directory"
commit=$(git commit-tree $root_tree -m "$commit_msg")

echo ---- create a branch...
git branch master $commit

# output the ids:
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo "empty tree:" $empty_tree
echo "root tree: " $root_tree
echo "commit:    " $commit
```

Comment: This indeed adds the empty tree to the repository. But cloning the repo does not create the empty directory in your working tree.

Comment: for non-believers: `git archive master | tar tv` :-)